# How to import variables from a sub CMakeLists.txt into the top-level CMakeLists.txt?

Tags: cmake

I'm working with a CMake project that has the following directory structure for a library named `foo`:

```
foo/
 |  subfolder/
 |   |  A.h
 |   |  A.cpp
 |   |  B.h
 |   |  B.cpp
 |  C.h
 |  C.cpp
 |  D.h
 |  D.cpp
 |  CMakeLists.txt
```

In the initial configuration, the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` looked like this:

```
add_library(foo
        STATIC
        subfolder/A.h
        subfolder/A.cpp
        subfolder/B.h
        subfolder/B.cpp
        C.h
        C.cpp
        D.h
        D.cpp
)

target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

However, I prefer not to use `subfolder/...` directly within the `CMakeLists.txt` file and decided to create a `CMakeLists.txt` file inside the `subfolder`, intending to import its variables into the top-level `CMakeLists.txt`. Here's the updated directory structure:

```
foo/
 |  subfolder/
 |   |  A.h
 |   |  A.cpp
 |   |  B.h
 |   |  B.cpp
 |   |  CMakeLists.txt
 |  C.h
 |  C.cpp
 |  D.h
 |  D.cpp
 |  CMakeLists.txt
```

Contents of `subfolder/CMakeLists.txt`:

```
set(SUB_SRC
   A.h
   A.cpp
   B.h
   B.cpp
)
```

And here's the updated top `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
# Include the sub CMakeLists.txt to import variables
include(subfolder/CMakeLists.txt) # Not working!
add_library(foo
    STATIC
    ${SUB_SRC}
    C.h
    C.cpp
    D.h
    D.cpp
)

target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

I have tried using `include(subfolder/CMakeLists.txt)` but it is not working!

**Question**: How can I import the sub `CMakeLists.txt` file inside the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` to be able to use the `SUB_SRC` variable? Alternatively, please suggest another approach if this is not the right way.

Comment: Sink the `add_library` call down to the subdirectory CMakeLists.txt. The created target will still be visibile at the toplevel dir.

Comment: You probably want to mark your `set` as `PARENT_SCOPE`.
e.g. `set(SUB_SRC A.h A.cpp ... PARENT_SCOPE)`.

If you want to have another level of depth, you can either set it as a cached variable or a property.

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-cache-entry

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set_property.html#set-property

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/get_property.html#get-property

Comment: Just my two cents but the initial configuration looked cleaner, had no surprises and was more robust.

Comment: @Friedrich, when you create a new class, it's best to have the CMakeLists file in the same folder. Otherwise, you'll have to search up through the folders to find the right CMakeLists file, especially if you have lots of folders – that can be tricky. Also, when you include a file, you'll have to write something like `#include "folderA/folderB/.../SomeClass.h"`, which isn't very convenient.

Comment: The first `CMakeLists.txt` you find should also be the right one. I agree that long-ish paths in `#include` directives are a code smell. One would typically use `target_include_directories` to get them straight. It's your project so knock yourself out.

Comment: @Gabriel, Using `PARENT_SCOPE` does the job, but I like my solution better because it lets me use a shorter `#include "C.h"` instead of the longer `#include "subfolder/C.h"`. Caching variables in CMake is for something else – it's for when you want to let users change variables in your library, but I don't need that for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Abdo21 not necessarily, you can mark them as advanced and use a specific prefix so that users don't touch them. They are a lot less cumbersome to use than the get/set properties I've linked.

Answer (score 0):

Following @arrowd's comment, I created a sub-library and linked it to the main CMake file.

subfolder/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(subfolder
        STATIC
        A.h
        A.cpp
        B.h
        B.cpp
)

target_include_directories(subfolder INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

main CMakeLists.txt

```
add_subdirectory(subfolder)

add_library(foo
    STATIC
    C.h
    C.cpp
    D.h
    D.cpp
)

target_link_libraries(foo subfolder)

target_include_directories(foo INTERFACE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```